# How to configure nginx properly to show SPA application?

Tags: nginx, server, devops, nginx-config

I'm setting up a new server and I want to use Nginx to deploy my application which is written in Angular. How the nginx config should look like?

This is a new VPS OVH server. I already installed Nginx on this server then I tried to configure Nginx to display even static index.html when I came into "my-app.com". Unfortunately, I always get an error that "This page is unreachable".

I'm passing there my configs:

```py
nginx-conf:


user root;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid   /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {

}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application.octet-stream;

        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


}
```

Then I got 2 additional configs in conf.d:

```py
default.conf

server {
    listen         [::]:80;
    server_name    my-api.com www.my-api.com;
    root           /var/www/html;
    index          index.html;
    try_files $uri  $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Okay, and the last one:

```py
my-app.com.conf

server {
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name    my-api.com www.my-api.com;
    root           /var/www/html;
    index          index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

And after commands:
nginx -T (tests are okay), then I'm stopping Nginx by "sudo service nginx stop" command and starting it again. After getting to the browser and pass link "my-app.com" still the error is there. My expected result is just come to this page "my-app.com" and see my application. Even static HTML - that would show me that I'm making something correct.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two additional configs are the same, and you only need one of those. That said, you have your NGINX configured with `server_name    my-api.com www.my-api.com;`. This means that only if your request URI is `my-api.com` or `www.my-api.com` NGINX will attempt to use this configuration. You can remove the server_name line to make NGINX use this configuration for every url it receives. (eg. `http://{serverip}/` or `http://{domain}/`)

The domain you are using (I'm assuming it isn't literally `my-api.com`) probably isn't configured to your webserver.
Your domain should have an A record pointing to your werbserver's external IP address, and your webserver's firewall should have port 80 TCP open.

Also, you have `listen      [::]:80;`, I'm not 100% sure, but I think this implies the usage of ipv6. Try just using `listen      80;`

Try checking your domain's DNS settings, to make sure they are correct and change your config to

```
server {
    listen      80;
    root           /var/www/html;
    index          index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Be sure to have the build version of your Angular application in the `/var/www/html` folder of the server.

Comment: Thank you for your response :) I changed everything into this config which you showed me and probably you're right that my domain is not configured to my webserver. Do you know some kind of tutorial how can I do that? I'm really bad with these things... Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Can you access your webserver using its public IP adress?
(eg. http://{internalIP}/ or http://{externalIP}/)

If none work, you server is configured wrong.
If only the local IP works, your firewall is configured wrong.
If both work, and the domain doesn't, the domain is configured wrong.

Your domain registrar should have a webtool where you can simply enter your external IP adress.

Comment: Thank you for your help Anderio, You're amazing!

Comment: Everything works fine now. But I got one issue with SPA path. If I go to "my-app.com" - application is loaded and everything is okay. There's one issue when you went to some kind of route - then refresh manually page. I'm getting redirected from "my-app.com/list" to "my-app.com". How can I stay on this "path" but still use 'indedx.html' from the same path which we used at the start?

Comment: try   
`location / {
      root /var/www/html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}` but remove the root, index, and try_files already in your config.